# when i parse my http response to object in angular 2 it don't parse the functions?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, jsonparser

this is my typescript class

```
import { Hours } from "./hours";


export class Day {
            public dayName: string;
            public dayId: number;
            public dayStatus: string = "Closed";
            public checked: boolean = false;
            public hours: Hours[] = new Array();


consturctor() {

}


public equals( dayid: number ): boolean {

    if ( this.dayId == dayid ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public isChecked() {
    let result: boolean;
    if ( this.dayStatus == "Open" ) {
        result = true;
    }
    else {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

when i send this object to my rest service which is in java spring it save the object into the database but when i get this object back from the database i get all the fields but when i try to access the equals method i get error that equal is not a method . the *proto* of the response is below

```
      __proto__
     :
      constructor
      :
    ƒ Object()
    hasOwnProperty
    :
    ƒ hasOwnProperty()
    isPrototypeOf
    :
    ƒ isPrototypeOf()
    propertyIsEnumerable
    :
    ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
    toLocaleString
    :
    ƒ toLocaleString()
    toString
    :
   ƒ ()
     valueOf
   :
   ƒ valueOf()
  __defineGetter__
   :
   ƒ __defineGetter__()
  __defineSetter__
   :
   ƒ __defineSetter__()
   __lookupGetter__
     :
    ƒ __lookupGetter__()
    __lookupSetter__
     :
    ƒ __lookupSetter__()
    get __proto__
    :
     ƒ __proto__()
    set __proto__
     :
      ƒ __proto__()
```

it does not have equal method in it . if i do a new Day(); i get the equal method  below is the code how i get the request

```
       this.http.get(url,options).map((res)=>res.json()).
       subscribe((data)=>{ obj=data});
```

** EDIT **

this is the json i sent to server

```
    Day
    checked: true
    dayId:1
    dayName:"Monday"
    dayStatus:"Open" 
    hours:[Hours]
    __proto__:
     consturctor:ƒ ()
     equals:ƒ (dayid)
     isChecked:ƒ ()
     constructor:ƒ Day() 
    __proto__:Object
```

it become this in the request body

```
          {
  "dayStatus": "Open",
  "checked": true,
  "hours": [
    {
      "startAt": "00:00",
      "closeAt": "23:59",
      "maxPatientNo": "20"
    }
  ],
  "dayId": 4,
  "dayName": "Thursday"
}
```

i get all the fields .

Comment: Could you include an example of JSON you are sending to the server?
Also, an example of JSON you receive from back from the server when you do the `http.get`?
Typically only data is sent to the server. When you get the data from the server in subsequent queries, you just construct a new instance of teh class from that data.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, typically you

- interact with data on client-side
- send the data to your server (for validation/persistence/etc.)

When you query the server for this data later, you receive the, well, **data**. Behavior is not transmitted through the wire, if you need to you can just construct a new instance of a class from that data.

For example, with the following implementation:

```
export class Day {
    public dayName: string;
    public dayId: number;
    public dayStatus: string;
    public checked: boolean;
    public hours: Hours[];


    // the default constructor
    constructor(name: string, id: number, status?: string, checked?: boolean, hours?: Hours[]) {
        this.dayName = name;
        this.dayId = id;
        this.dayStatus = status || 'closed';
        this.checked = checked || false;
        this.hours = hours || [];
    }

    // static method that calls the constructor
    // this is just like a constructor overload in other languages
    public static fromObject(object: any) {
        const {dayName, dayId, dayStatus, checked, hours} = object;
        return new this(dayName, dayId, dayStatus, checked, hours);
    }


    public equals( dayid: number ): boolean {

        if ( this.dayId == dayid ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public isChecked() {
        let result: boolean;
        if ( this.dayStatus == "Open" ) {
            result = true;
        }
        else {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

You can use it like so:

```
this.http.get(url, options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map(parsed => Day.fromObject(parsed))
    .subscribe(day => this.receivedDay = day);
```

Comment: you are right it only send the data of the object but i want to know is there a way by which i can convert my response into new object the method you used above work fine but issue is that in this day object there is  an array of hour object and hour object also have equals method which check if that hour is equal or not so even if i use new Day() i still get error when i use  hour.equal method .

Comment: @ashutosh When you parse the object, you might as well do `hourInstances = parsed.hours.map(parsedHours => Hours.from(parsedHours)` and then pass the `hourInstances` to `Day` constructor. There isn't a good reason to store behaviour methods on server-side.

Comment: @ashutosh As long as you can reconstruct a class from its properties, native `JSON.stringify` will be enough and will work for you. It would also properly stringify the nested class instances' properties.  If you, however, need some special serialization, I suppose you could also add some sort of `.toJSON` methods to your classes.

Comment: i agree i don't want to store behavior method on server i was looking for some sort of function in angular which can solve this solution for now i am also thinking about creating a serialization method in the class should i create a constructor with parameter or create a new object in that method and return it as result .

Comment: @ashutosh I am not quite sure what sort of function you are looking for. What problem are you trying to solve here, exactly?

Comment: i was looking for a solution which can convert my java object into java script object when i use assignment i get the object and is property but it give me error for the function but when i create a object using new object() and then assign the variable one by one i can use the method i get no error at last i wrote a deserialize method which do this for me .